# mysql to show all data excluding current month for unixtime

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I need to show records which are dateadd excluding current month in mysql. Dateadded is a unixtime stamp and I am struggling with this. Please could someone help.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
order_no,from_unixtime(dateadded) order_date
FROM Orders
WHERE
from_unixtime(dateadd) > LAST_DAY(date) 
OR from_unixtime(dateadd) < DATE_FORMAT(current_date,'%Y-%m-01')
;
```

Comment: Thank you but this does not return any row of data.

Comment: Hi avisheks,I have built the schema with following id #!9/c4870

Comment: my fault, there would be OR instead of AND, edited the ans, try now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try-

```
dateadd > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()),'%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')) AND dateadd < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y-%m-01 00:00:00'))
```

Note: In this way query will use index on dateadd field.

Comment: Hi Zafar, the above query does not return any data

Comment: does table contain data out of current month.

Comment: yes it does for last 9 months worth of data is there

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
`dateadded` <= (unix_timestamp(concat(year(now()),'-',month(now()),'-01'))-1))